# Is this function computable? Is this reduction correct?

Tags: computability

Let $A$ be a set, $K=\{x:\phi_x(x)\downarrow\}$. Let c to be a total computable function such that $\phi_{c(x,y,n)}(z)=\begin{cases}\phi_n(z) & \text{if }\phi_x(y)\downarrow\\\uparrow &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

Suppose $\forall x,y\exists a.\phi_x(y)\downarrow \Leftrightarrow c(x, y,a)\in A$.

The question is if the function:
$f(x)=a$ such that $x\in K \Leftrightarrow c(x, x, a)\in A$
is total computable.

Hence, can I prove $K\leq _m A$ with $c(x,x, f(x))$ as reduction function?

Comment: I guess, in the formula $\forall x\exists a.\phi_x(y)\downarrow \Leftrightarrow c(x, y,a)\in A$, the $y$ is universally quantified?

Comment: yes it is, thank you

Comment: I doubt $K$ is just any nonrecursive set.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo thank you, I have corrected

Comment: Are you sure that $y$ does not depend on $a$?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo sure. But I'm not sure we can prove it, it was just an exercise I was wondering.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo My teacher says we can just assume there is that function which finds the "a" with that property, and is total computable. I am not sure about it